# Attempting to draw a square using orthographic projection and having trouble

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glkit

I'm running this code on the iPhone and am using the GLKit provided by Apple for matrices.  On the iPhone I only get a grey screen but I should have a square drawing in the corner but it isn't showing up.

I don't see anything wrong with what I've done and calls to OpenGL's getError return GL_NO_ERROR.

My source:

- [ViewController.m](http://pastebin.com/Bg3AxRqW)
- [Vertex Shader](http://pastebin.com/MPftvHFf)
- [Fragment Shader](http://pastebin.com/kVjZs8Cy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of code to go through there, though I see one potential problem, is that you are missing a call to [`glEnableVertexAttribArray`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glEnableVertexAttribArray.xml).

You'll need something like:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(attributes[ATTRIB_VERTEX]);
```

before your call to `glDrawElements`. Not sure if there's any other errors, but that's the only thing I saw.